# php5-fpm invoked oom-killer

Tags: php-fpm, php5, dmesg

One of my server (Ubuntu 12.04, 16CPU, 32GB RAM) runs the app section of my website (Nginx 1.1.19, PHP5-FPM, Php 5.3.10, Symfony2 Web Framework)

Suddenly, users started getting HTTP 5** Errors. When I went on the server, there was huge disk IO and the culprit was `[flush]`.

When I went through the kernel logs using `dmesg`, it showed the reason for `[flush]` was `php5-fpm invoked oom-killer`

**Kernel Log entry from the time of Incident:**

```
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295736] php5-fpm invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x280da, order=0, oom_adj=0, oom_score_adj=0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295740] php5-fpm cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295743] Pid: 13310, comm: php5-fpm Not tainted 3.2.0-69-virtual #103-Ubuntu
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295744] Call Trace:
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295751]  [<ffffffff8111b971>] dump_header+0x91/0xe0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295754]  [<ffffffff8111bd25>] oom_kill_process+0x85/0xb0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295757]  [<ffffffff8111c0ca>] out_of_memory+0xfa/0x220
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295761]  [<ffffffff81121aa3>] __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x8c3/0x8e0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295764]  [<ffffffff8115a853>] alloc_pages_vma+0xb3/0x190
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295768]  [<ffffffff8113ae9c>] do_anonymous_page.isra.38+0x7c/0x2f0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295772]  [<ffffffff8113e921>] handle_pte_fault+0x1e1/0x200
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295777]  [<ffffffff8165d9be>] ? _raw_spin_lock+0xe/0x20
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295780]  [<ffffffff8113c089>] ? __pte_alloc+0xa9/0x160
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295782]  [<ffffffff8113fb19>] handle_mm_fault+0x269/0x370
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295785]  [<ffffffff81661504>] do_page_fault+0x184/0x550
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295789]  [<ffffffff81013728>] ? __switch_to+0x138/0x360
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295793]  [<ffffffff8105668d>] ? set_next_entity+0xad/0xd0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295796]  [<ffffffff8105682a>] ? finish_task_switch+0x4a/0xf0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295799]  [<ffffffff8165b6ec>] ? __schedule+0x3cc/0x6f0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295802]  [<ffffffff8165e135>] page_fault+0x25/0x30
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295804] Mem-Info:
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295805] Node 0 DMA per-cpu:
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295808] CPU    0: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295809] CPU    1: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295810] CPU    2: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295812] CPU    3: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295813] CPU    4: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295814] CPU    5: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295816] CPU    6: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295817] CPU    7: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295819] CPU    8: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295820] CPU    9: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295822] CPU   10: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295823] CPU   11: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295824] CPU   12: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295826] CPU   13: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295827] CPU   14: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295828] CPU   15: hi:    0, btch:   1 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295830] Node 0 DMA32 per-cpu:
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295831] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295833] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295834] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295836] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295837] CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295838] CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295840] CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295841] CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295842] CPU    8: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295844] CPU    9: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295845] CPU   10: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295846] CPU   11: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295848] CPU   12: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295850] CPU   13: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295851] CPU   14: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295853] CPU   15: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295854] Node 0 Normal per-cpu:
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295856] CPU    0: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:  15
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295857] CPU    1: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295859] CPU    2: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295860] CPU    3: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295861] CPU    4: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295863] CPU    5: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295864] CPU    6: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295865] CPU    7: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295867] CPU    8: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295868] CPU    9: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295870] CPU   10: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295871] CPU   11: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295872] CPU   12: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295874] CPU   13: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295875] CPU   14: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295877] CPU   15: hi:  186, btch:  31 usd:   0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295880] active_anon:7408050 inactive_anon:436 isolated_anon:0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295881]  active_file:21159 inactive_file:33077 isolated_file:419
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295882]  unevictable:0 dirty:36283 writeback:0 unstable:0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295882]  free:47243 slab_reclaimable:20065 slab_unreclaimable:15299
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295883]  mapped:15592 shmem:138 pagetables:28362 bounce:0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295885] Node 0 DMA free:15908kB min:32kB low:40kB high:48kB active_anon:0kB inactive_anon:0kB active_file:0kB inactive_file:0kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:15652kB mlocked:0kB dirty:0kB writeback:0kB mapped:0kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:0kB slab_unreclaimable:0kB kernel_stack:0kB pagetables:0kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:0 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295892] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 3760 30220 30220
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295895] Node 0 DMA32 free:114216kB min:8404kB low:10504kB high:12604kB active_anon:3651120kB inactive_anon:284kB active_file:7848kB inactive_file:38464kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):0kB present:3850496kB mlocked:0kB dirty:38664kB writeback:0kB mapped:272kB shmem:0kB slab_reclaimable:8444kB slab_unreclaimable:7164kB kernel_stack:208kB pagetables:10056kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:116761 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295902] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 26460 26460
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295905] Node 0 Normal free:58848kB min:59144kB low:73928kB high:88716kB active_anon:25981080kB inactive_anon:1460kB active_file:76788kB inactive_file:93844kB unevictable:0kB isolated(anon):0kB isolated(file):1676kB present:27095040kB mlocked:0kB dirty:106468kB writeback:0kB mapped:62096kB shmem:552kB slab_reclaimable:71816kB slab_unreclaimable:54032kB kernel_stack:2352kB pagetables:103392kB unstable:0kB bounce:0kB writeback_tmp:0kB pages_scanned:388409 all_unreclaimable? yes
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295912] lowmem_reserve[]: 0 0 0 0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295915] Node 0 DMA: 1*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 1*32kB 2*64kB 1*128kB 1*256kB 0*512kB 1*1024kB 1*2048kB 3*4096kB = 15908kB
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295922] Node 0 DMA32: 268*4kB 544*8kB 367*16kB 391*32kB 271*64kB 165*128kB 103*256kB 32*512kB 5*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 114240kB
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295929] Node 0 Normal: 13697*4kB 0*8kB 0*16kB 0*32kB 0*64kB 0*128kB 0*256kB 0*512kB 0*1024kB 0*2048kB 1*4096kB = 58884kB
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295937] 54555 total pagecache pages
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295938] 0 pages in swap cache
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295939] Swap cache stats: add 0, delete 0, find 0/0
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295940] Free swap  = 0kB
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.295941] Total swap = 0kB
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359778] 7864304 pages RAM
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359780] 144336 pages reserved
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359781] 654931 pages shared
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359782] 7618451 pages non-shared
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359783] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss cpu oom_adj oom_score_adj name
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359798] [  445]     0   445     4800      221   4       0             0 rpcbind
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359801] [  452]   108   452     5376      279   2       0             0 rpc.statd
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359804] [  482]     0   482     4308       94   0       0             0 upstart-udev-br
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359807] [  494]     0   494     5431      327   1     -17         -1000 udevd
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359809] [  608]     0   608     5430      231   1     -17         -1000 udevd
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359812] [  624]     0   624     5430      233   3     -17         -1000 udevd
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359815] [  706]     0   706     3797       49   3       0             0 upstart-socket-
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359818] [  882]     0   882     1816      213   6       0             0 dhclient3
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359821] [  993]     0   993    12509      499   2     -17         -1000 sshd
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359824] [ 1018]   101  1018    63430      480   4       0             0 rsyslogd
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359827] [ 1040]   102  1040     5954      155  13       0             0 dbus-daemon
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359830] [ 1048]     0  1048     7445      153   9       0             0 rpc.idmapd
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359832] [ 1151]     0  1151     3626      190   3       0             0 getty
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359835] [ 1157]     0  1157     3626      189   1       0             0 getty
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359837] [ 1162]     0  1162     3626      189   5       0             0 getty
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359840] [ 1163]     0  1163     3626      188   1       0             0 getty
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359842] [ 1165]     0  1165     3626      188   6       0             0 getty
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359845] [ 1170]     0  1170     4778      211   4       0             0 cron
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359847] [ 1171]     0  1171     4227       89  12       0             0 atd
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359850] [ 1172]     0  1172     1082      149  10       0             0 acpid
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359852] [ 1178]     0  1178     3995      173   0       0             0 irqbalance
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359855] [ 1179]   103  1179    46916      650  10       0             0 whoopsie
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359858] [ 1195]   106  1195    80805      236   5       0             0 memcached
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359861] [ 1228]   109  1228     4199       99   0       0             0 nrsysmond
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359863] [ 1230]   109  1230    62851     1327   0       0             0 nrsysmond
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359866] [ 1340]     0  1340     4164      105   9       0             0 newrelic-daemon
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359869] [ 1341]     0  1341    61114     1948  13       0             0 newrelic-daemon
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359871] [ 1381]     0  1381     3310      100   6       0             0 mdadm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359874] [ 1444]     0  1444     3626      189   0       0             0 getty
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359877] [ 1445]     0  1445     3188      177   3       0             0 getty
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359879] [ 1890]     0  1890   369259     2517   3       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359882] [ 1916]     0  1916    20056     1040   8       0             0 nginx
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359885] [ 1917]    33  1917    20473     1994   8       0             0 nginx
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359887] [ 1918]    33  1918    20399     1927   0       0             0 nginx
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359890] [ 1919]    33  1919    20454     2020   7       0             0 nginx
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359893] [ 1920]    33  1920    20201     1775   5       0             0 nginx
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359896] [ 6544]    33  6544   624267    32944   6       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359898] [ 7293]    33  7293   618265    25932   9       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359901] [ 7381]    33  7381   618555    26851  12       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359904] [ 8280]    33  8280   618008    27712   2       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359906] [ 8737]    33  8737   619699    27793   6       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359909] [ 8908]    33  8908   618037    26037   6       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359912] [ 9093]    33  9093   618471    25848   2       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359914] [ 9479]    33  9479   688805    75927   6       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359917] [ 9503]    33  9503  5636713  4312476  15       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359919] [10392]    33 10392   621196    28967  13       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359922] [10509]    33 10509   618070    26222   0       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359925] [10510]    33 10510   622084    30147   2       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359927] [10540]    33 10540   620672    29171  11       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359930] [10799]    33 10799   670237    78421   4       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359932] [11066]    33 11066   616125    23836   0       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359935] [11250]    33 11250   619613    27729   0       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359937] [11254]    33 11254   619605    27515   0       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359940] [11426]    33 11426   620759    28353   9       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359943] [11428]    33 11428   618500    24942   9       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359945] [11429]    33 11429   832300   131639  12       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359948] [11444]    33 11444   390293    26564  12       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359951] [12119]    33 12119   389579    26295   2       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359953] [12542]    33 12542   390336    27483  11       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359956] [12577]    33 12577  1770706  1177669   2       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359958] [13310]    33 13310  1559195  1166076  11       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359961] [13481]    33 13481   729336   121410   9       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359963] [14074]    33 14074   613987    21729  15       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359966] [14686]    33 14686   405943    20594   6       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359968] [14771]    33 14771  1341333    17036  10       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359971] [14814]    33 14814   375034    16151   2       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359973] [14888]    33 14888   374759    15618   9       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359976] [14917]    33 14917   382071    16366  11       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359979] [14919]    33 14919   373976    14146   2       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359981] [14982]    33 14982   373012    11466   0       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359984] [14983]    33 14983   372940    10379   0       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359986] [14984]    33 14984   374522    12917  14       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359989] [14985]    33 14985   372898     9890   7       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359991] [14986]    33 14986   373733    11996  15       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359994] [14987]    33 14987   373203    12061   2       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359996] [14988]    33 14988   373368    12404  13       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.359999] [14989]    33 14989   372407     8838   9       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360002] [14990]    33 14990   373491    11722   0       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360004] [14991]    33 14991   371987     8545   2       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360007] [14992]    33 14992   372184     9768  12       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360010] [14993]    33 14993   375221    12528   6       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360012] [15011]    33 15011   372181     8558  11       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360015] [15012]    33 15012   374863    13426   9       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360018] [15013]    33 15013   372497    10278   0       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360020] [15014]    33 15014   372489     9905   8       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360023] [15015]    33 15015   373200    11024   0       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360026] [15017]    33 15017   372621     9203   2       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360028] [15018]    33 15018   371993     9152  12       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360031] [15019]    33 15019   374082    10949   0       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360033] [15020]    33 15020   373137    10112  11       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360036] [15021]    33 15021   377055    14606   0       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360038] [15027]    33 15027   372243     9148   9       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360041] [15028]    33 15028   373802    11787  12       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360044] [15029]    33 15029   372094     7847  11       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360046] [15030]    33 15030   372093     7475   2       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360049] [15031]    33 15031   372606     9650  15       0             0 php5-fpm
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.360071] Out of memory: Kill process 9503 (php5-fpm) score 564 or sacrifice child
Jan 31 12:39:01 ip-10-0-0-160 kernel: [78817.363179] Killed process 9503 (php5-fpm) total-vm:22546852kB, anon-rss:17203684kB, file-rss:46220kB
```

Seems like the issue is with php5-fpm overcommiting the memory for some cases.

How do I ensure that such cases, doesn't create HIGH DISK IO / Server Unstable?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you don't run too many PHP-FPM processes on your server. Look at `pm.max_children`, `pm.min_spare_servers` and `pm.max_spare_servers` settings in your PHP-FPM pool configuration.